# Query filter continuously dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with dates sequence and some columns

```
date    shop    is_virtual  flag
2024-02-25  shop1   0   0
2024-02-24  shop1   1   1
2024-02-23  shop1   1   1
2024-02-22  shop1   1   1
2024-02-21  shop1   0   0
2024-02-20  shop1   0   0
2024-02-19  shop1   1   0
2024-02-18  shop1   1   0
2024-02-17  shop1   0   0
2024-02-16  shop1   1   1
2024-02-15  shop1   1   1
2024-02-14  shop1   1   1
2024-02-13  shop1   1   1
2024-02-12  shop1   0   0
2024-02-11  shop1   1   0
```

I wish to create the column flag which has 1 only if more than N (in this example 3) days continuously have is_virtual = 1

Any ideas appreciated.

Sample data in consumable format

```
WITH CTE(date,shop,is_virtual) AS
(
  SELECT  '2024-02-25','shop1',0 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-24','shop1',1 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-23','shop1',1 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-22','shop1',1 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-21','shop1',0 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-20','shop1',0 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-19','shop1',1 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-18','shop1',1 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-17','shop1',0 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-16','shop1',1 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-15','shop1',1 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-14','shop1',1 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-13','shop1',1 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-12','shop1',0 UNION ALL
  SELECT'2024-02-11','shop1',1 
)
 SELECT C.* FROM CTE AS C
```

I've got correct result using this query, but maybe it is a bit "dirty"

```
SELECT date, [is_virtual], flag, flag1
    , flag_result = CASE WHEN flag1 >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM (
    SELECT date, [is_virtual], flag
        , flag1 = SUM(CAST([is_virtual] AS int) ) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY [is_virtual])
    FROM (
        SELECT date, [is_virtual], flag
            , grp = SUM(CASE WHEN [is_virtual] = prev THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER ORDER BY date)
        FROM (
            SELECT *
                , prev = LAG([is_virtual]) OVER (ORDER BY date)
            FROM [doexercises].[dbo].[osa1]
        ) s
    ) s1
) s2
```

Comment: Search for "gaps and islands" and the results will show many SQL solutions to this classic problem. Try to apply the technique for your specific need and add your attempt to your question, even if not working.

Comment: I have checked 'gaps and islands' thanks. Sorry to not providing DDL + DML

Comment: "which has 1 only if more than N - 3 in this example" - more than 2 actually, its not more than 3,  its 3 or more.

Comment: @DaleK , could you check my comment, please?

Comment: @Alexander can you check my comment please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the difference in row numbers technique to identify blocks with no change in value. Then use a windowed count to see if it meets your criteria

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT C.*
        -- Common technique for detecting sequential blocks
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date)
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY is_virtual ORDER BY date) cont_group
    FROM MyTable AS C
)
SELECT date, shop, is_virtual
  -- Flag condition using windowed count
  , CASE
  WHEN
      is_virtual = 1
      AND COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY is_virtual, cont_group) >= 3
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END flag
FROM cte
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D6DSVYLR)

Comment: is it correct? that 
2024-02-12  shop1   0   0 was added to the same cont_group as 

2024-02-16  shop1   1   1
2024-02-15  shop1   1   1
2024-02-14  shop1   1   1
2024-02-13  shop1   1   1

Comment: It gives the exact results you asked for.

Comment: @Alexander I think are you looking at the `cont_group` values? Yes that is fine that we group that shop with them, because for the final calculation we filter on both that condition **and** `is_virtual = 1` so its ignored in the calculation of `flag`. As I said its returning the exact results you asked for.